# "Format Code" like in Eclipse

Tags: indentation, whitespace, formatting

In Eclipse, I can hit `CTRL + SHIFT + F` which not only corrects the indentation but also whitespace (for example: `c=a +b ;` is corrected to `c = a + b;`) and the line length. I am looking for a similar tool for Emacs. All I know is `C-x h TAB` that corrects the indentation, but nothing more. Do you know any automatic way how to completely format a (espacially C/C++) source file in Emacs?

Comment: Nope. However, it shouldn't be too hard to write an integration for an external tool, such as AStyle or ClangFormat. Here's a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier

Comment: For indenting, you can do it faster with the command [prelude-cleanup-buffer-or-region](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/cba761c21283b45f8228877773da9527607b8db1/core/prelude-core.el#L278). Copy the  function definition and [prelude-indent-sensitive-modes](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/37101cb867b81a61ccb7b216a3c053bc465cee06/core/prelude-custom.el#L79) in your `init.el`. Then bind the command to a key like `C-c i` and use it whenever you want to indent without cursor moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) to achieve this. After installing the `clang-format` tool, you can use [`clang-format.el`](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.el) to perform the appropriate actions from emacs. `clang-format.el` is also available from [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/clang-format). The emacs commands provided are `clang-format-buffer` and `clang-format-region` which you can bind as you need. Note that you can customize formatting options by using a `.clang-format` file located in an ancestor directory.

Comment: Ah, so the integration already exists. Note, however, that MELPA distributes a different (apparently newer) version than the one you linked to.

Comment: Clang-Format is indeed a great tool, well integrated into Emacs. To have the same binding as in Eclipse you can use the following in a your C/C++ mode hook `(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-S-f") 'clang-format-region)`. In recent versions `clang-format` supports also some other languages such as Javascript and Java, see LanguageKind in this page: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: Okay, this works nearly well, has only one weakness: spaces in closing angles in nested template arguments are removed: `List<pair<int, int> >` -> `List<pair<int, int>> //Error!`

Comment: @user3000316 Check the options for the config value "Standard" [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). You can set it to `Cpp03` to fix this issue.