# C++ Incorrect Enum Indentation

Tags: indentation, c++, cc-mode

It seems like cc-mode indentation is working rather well, however I seem to have run into a minor issue when creating a few enums in C++.

Emacs seems to handle almost all kinds of enums rather well now, even the "enum class" types, however, for some reason the following one seems broken:

```
class Test
{
public:
    enum t1
    {
        T0 = 1,
            T1,   <----- ?
            T2 = 3
            };
};
```

Removing the "t1" identifier fixes the "incorrect" indentation, but the identifier is still desirable in some cases.

So, the the "correct" indentation would be:

```
class Test
{
public:
    enum t1
    {
        T0 = 1,
        T1,
        T2 = 3
    };
};
```

Is there any way of fixing this, and do anyone know if this is the intended behavior?

This occurs with GNU Emacs 25.0.50.4, with accompanying cc-mode. Running with `--no-init-file` produces the same results, although with gnu-style indentation.

Comment: I did not have any problem with your whole enum. I'm using Emacs 24.4.1. Do you have any configuration related to C++ or indentation?

Comment: I do have plenty of C++ configuration, but running with --no-init-file produces the same results, although with gnu-style indentation instead. I'll see if I can replicate it 24.4 later on at home. Otherwise, I guess it's a bug in cc-mode then?

Comment: Maybe there's in development changes. Also, I'm using `linux` style by default.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you don't mind relying on clang, `clang-format` is a wonderful tool. A small description [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/format-code-like-in-eclipse/4188#4188).

Comment: Answered in depth on Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497374/emacs-cc-mode-indentation-problem-with-c0x-enum-class - along with reference code for a partial fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If it happens with `emacs -Q`, file a bug report with `M-x bug-report`.
- If you verify that this doesn't happen on Emacs 24.4, you can even:

  - Send an email to the dev list. It's likely that the person who inadvertently introduced the bug will immediately know what's happening.
  - Open the ChangeLog file and search for changes to the affected package. There should be something related to indentation in there, and it will be easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

check http://blog.binchen.org/posts/ccjava-code-indentation-in-emacs.html

Simply put, Emacs will assign indention according to the **c-syntax-context** which is the key to query global tree **c-offsets-alist**, the query result is the indention offset.

Then you need hack the function c-indent-line which is defined in /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes/cc-cmds.el to print out the actual value of c-syntax-context.

As I mentioned in the article, "M-x c-set-offset" will also print the context. The reason I don't use it because it's **NOT** reliable. There is nothing more reliable than hacking the actual code.

Comment: Isn't it easier to hit `C-c C-s` (= `c-show-syntactic-information`)  ?

Comment: "M-x c-set-offset" will also give the value of c-syntax-context. as mentioned in article. It basically does the same thing as c-show-syntactic-information. I don't remember details now, but "c-set-offset" does NOT work reliably, looks the command you recommended get the same result as c-set-offset by testing the two case in my article.

Comment: `There is nothing more reliable than hacking the actual code.` - Can't argue with that.